# How can I turn a country x year frequency table into another data frame containing only years of occurrences in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data. Frame which is the frequency table of countries and years from another data frame. I would like to turn this data.frame into a latex table with countries and years included, but instead of frequency I would like to get only the years with data. For example, suppose I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("Argentina", "Germany", "Korea"),
                "1994" = c(0,2,5),
                "1998" = c(1,0,0),
                "2002" = c(3,0,1))

df

> df
    country X1994 X1998 X2002
1 Argentina     0     1     3
2   Germany     2     0     0
3     Korea     5     0     1
```

(Not sure why "X"s were added before)
Is there a way to depart from the frequency table and get another table like the one bellow?

```
    country      years
1 Argentina 1998, 2002
2   Germany       1994
3     Korea 1994, 2002
```

In this table, only years with non-zeros were added in the column 'years', and the number of ocurrances is ignored. What matters is only if there is data or not.

Comment: The `X`s are added before because `data.frame` by default will convert "improper" column names (such as names beginning with a number) to standard names. You can disable that by setting `check.names = FALSE`. See the `?data.frame` help page for more explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R you can use `apply` and `paste(..., collapse = ", ")`:

```
df$years <- apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) 
                  paste(names(df[-1])[x > 0], collapse = ", "))
```

Output:

```
#     country  1994  1998  2002        years
# 1 Argentina     0     1     3   1998, 2002
# 2   Germany     2     0     0         1994
# 3     Korea     5     0     1   1994, 2002
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("Argentina", "Germany", "Korea"),
                 "1994" = c(0,2,5),
                 "1998" = c(1,0,0),
                 "2002" = c(3,0,1), 
                 check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

With dplyr:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-country) |> 
  filter(value > 0) |> 
  mutate(name = substring(name, 2)) |> 
  group_by(country) |> 
  summarize(years = paste(name, collapse = ", "))
#   country   years     
# 1 Argentina 1998, 2002
# 2 Germany   1994      
# 3 Korea     1994, 2002
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael! I am getting an error message: Error in summarize(group_by(mutate(filter(pivot_longer(df, -country),  : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default. Do you know what could it be?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe older package versions... Go for @jpsmith's solution. It looks neat.

Answer (score 2):

```r
df <- data.frame(country = c("Argentina", "Germany", "Korea"),
                 "1994" = c(0,2,5),
                 "1998" = c(1,0,0),
                 "2002" = c(3,0,1))
```

You could use a combinatiopn of `tidyr::pivot_longer()` and `tidyr::nest()`.
`xtable::xtable()` can create a Latex table.

```r
library(tidyverse)
result <- 
  pivot_longer(df, -country) |> 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, "X")) |> 
  filter(value > 0) |> 
  select(-value) |> 
  nest(data = name) |> 
  mutate(year = map(data, deframe),
         year = map_chr(year, paste, collapse = ", ")) |> 
  select(-data)
result
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   country   year      
#>   <chr>     <chr>     
#> 1 Argentina 1998, 2002
#> 2 Germany   1994      
#> 3 Korea     1994, 2002
         
library(xtable)
xtable(result)
#> % latex table generated in R 4.3.1 by xtable 1.8-4 package
#> % Mon Oct 23 12:21:34 2023
#> \begin{table}[ht]
#> \centering
#> \begin{tabular}{rll}
#>   \hline
#>  & country & year \\ 
#>   \hline
#> 1 & Argentina & 1998, 2002 \\ 
#>   2 & Germany & 1994 \\ 
#>   3 & Korea & 1994, 2002 \\ 
#>    \hline
#> \end{tabular}
#> \end{table}
```